# Issue with finding the height of the main UIView between a Navigation Controller and Tab Bar

Tags: ios

I recently had this issue of trying to find the displayed area of my view under an opaque tab bar and opaque navigation bar. The frame is evidently closer to the size of the screen (likely includes the tab and nav bar) than to what is visible and so my views were being hidden.

I would like to know if there is any official way of finding this view size and if there is any way to think about this programmatically, except maybe to subtract the tab bar and nav heights (and so ruin my app in a future change by Apple). Apple's own autolayout works just fine when pinning to the bottom of the UIView (ie. it does not go under the tab view).

Comment: This page is useful, but doesn't answer why the view is not init correctly, or how the value can be found in this scenario. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10425311/weird-positioning-issue-when-tabbar-is-present/10434171#10434171

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just get the screen size, and then subtract the known navigation bars and status bars.

```
+ (CGFloat) estimateViewHeightVertical: (UIViewController*)viewController
{
    CGRect screen_size = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGFloat screen_height = screen_size.size.height;

    CGFloat status_bar_height = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height;
    CGFloat tab_bar_controller_height = 0;
    CGFloat nav_bar_controller_height = 0;

    if (viewController.tabBarController)
    {
        tab_bar_controller_height = viewController.tabBarController.tabBar.frame.size.height;
    }
    if (viewController.navigationController)
    {
        nav_bar_controller_height = viewController.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height;
    }
    return screen_height - status_bar_height - nav_bar_controller_height - tab_bar_controller_height;
}
```